# Multiplying to convert epoch to nanoseconds adds 24 at the end?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using Python 3.8.5 and I am trying to get an epoch in nanosecond. However, I am realizing that multiplication with an epoch is having an odd behavior.
When I convert seconds to nanoseconds by multiplying by 1e9 and then convert to an int, 24 is added to the end. I've tried several ways around this, but the issues still seems to happen. I'd rather not use Decimal library. Is there any way around this?

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> import numpy as np
>>> dt = datetime(2021, 7, 7, 0, 0, 0, 1)
>>> dt.timestamp()
1625630400.000001
>>> dt.timestamp()*1e9
1.625630400000001e+18
>>> int(dt.timestamp()*1e9)
1625630400000001024
>>> np.datetime64(int(dt.timestamp()*1e9), "ns")
numpy.datetime64('2021-07-07T04:00:00.000001024')
```

Comment: It is the perennial only ~16 good decimal digits in a double precision variable question. The mantissa only has 53 bits to represent your number. It is this question ["Is floating point broken?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) but in another guise.